# Modify locally the "array" environment for Equation Systems

Tags: math-mode, spacing, lyx, environments, arrays

When I started to use LyX 2.0.6 I noticed that when an Equation System is needed, there are two options available to typeset it: using the appropriate command on the Math Line *cases*,

> [image]

or manually defining a left aligned matrix (*array envir.* in LaTeX code) delimited by a left curly brace,

> [image]

The result on the PDF is obivously different for the horizontal spacing because the first system thends to shifted on the left to compensate the space left blank by the second argument; but for the second method, the result is a simple centered system delimited by a half-mile-away braket. (Sorry if I couldn't show you the driect output).

Here is the basic MWE as the file is exported into normal LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\begin{document}
%
Cases environment:
\[
\begin{cases}
 x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
 x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
\end{cases}
\]
\par
Defined array environment:
\[
\left\{%
 \begin{array}{l}
  x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
  x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
 \end{array}%
\right.
\]
Only array environment:
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c 
\end{array}
\]
%
\end{document}
```

Since I want to use only the second method, to correct the position of the left braket I added this lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{array}{%    % this isn't applied to "matrices" and "cases"
 \addtolength{\arraycolsep}{-3.5pt}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}%
}
```

And this works fine for my purposes, **but** I want to use the array environment apart from this case, and as I do, the columns in the third example in the MWE result shrinked (the code I put works even if there isn't any equation system).

So in a document where the array is needed for both purposes, it works well for system but not alone by itself.

Then my question is: *Is there any macro/formatting trickery that permits to have the array environment following my code only if the character before is `\left{`*?

As I noticed, this behaviour would be similar to the function of `\@ifnextchar`, because if the next character is `\left{` then my code would apply, and otherwise don't, like this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{array}{%
% if "\left\{" inserted do A, otherwise B
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The `cases` environment

This is one solution that after this time came to my mind, so I'll be able to use LyX with the cases environment defined as the more advanced `dcases` by re-defining `cases` using `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}
\renewenvironment{cases}{%
 \begin{dcases}%
}{%
 \end{dcases}%\kern-\nulldelimiterspace%
}
%
\begin{document}
A centered formula for showing the center:
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
The new defined \texttt{cases} environment:
\[
\begin{cases}
 \int x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
 x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
\end{cases}
\]
Second method for \texttt{array} environment:
\[
\left\{%
 \begin{array}{l}
  \int x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
  x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
 \end{array}%
\right.
\]
%
\end{document}
```

The only thing that keeps me from inserting this lines inside my package `LyXbasic` is if this code does make some messing up with other math declarations.

So when inside LyX is typed this:

> [image]

The output is as follows:

> [image]

The difference in typesetting can be easily observed by a great improvement not only inside the pure LaTeX code but also "below" the command inside LyX.

### The `array` environment

In order to modify correctly the `array` environment it has to be added this lines of code before the single environment:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{array}{%
 \let\{\lbrace%
 \hskip-\arraycolsep%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{array}{%
 \kern-\nulldelimiterspace%
}
```

So if the single MWE is being added there will be a behaviour similar to `@{}l` using `\hskip-\arraycolsep`

```
\[
\left\{
 \begin{array}{l}
  x^n+y^n=z^n \\
  x^m+y^m=z^m 
 \end{array}
\right.
\]
\[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c \\
 a & b & c 
\end{array}
\]
```

The output is as follows:

> [image]

So now the common `arraycolsep` is not changed over the columns, but only aside the left delimiter.

Answer (score 4):

You want to avoid the `\tabcolsep` altogether; note also the correction for the null delimiter. You can use an optional argument to enlarge the leading in special cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{system}[1][1.1]
 {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}
  \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}
 {\end{array}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\begin{document}
A centered formula for showing the center:
\[
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\pi}
\]
The new \texttt{system} environment:
\[
\begin{system}
 x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
 x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
\end{system}
\]
Predefined \texttt{array} environment:
\[
\left\{%
 \begin{array}{l}
  x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
  x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
 \end{array}%
\right.
\]
A \texttt{system} environment with the optional argument:
\[
\begin{system}[1.5]
 x^{n}+y^{n}=z^{n}\\
 x^{m}+y^{m}=z^{m}
\end{system}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, clearly a *grazie* for the spacing correction, as I'll totally have to use later in my dissertation; but I'd like to know in the first place if there is some macro that can be inserted inside the LyX preamble to obtain two behaviours of `array`

Comment: @AndreaL. Just don't use LyX, why should you? My feeling is that it makes things more complicated, rather than easier.

Comment: As I thought initially, I began to familiarize with pure LaTeX (as the many examples posted worked out only without LyX), but I'd say I chose it as nothing more than a front-end.

Comment: @AndreaL. I don't understand what you're trying to do; define two different environments: distinct objects need distinct markup.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is define a command that inside the `\BeforeBeginEnvironment` of `array` reads if there is a `\left\{` or not: if yes it does apply my modifications to `arraycolsep`, if not it does nothing. Is it now a bit clearer?

Comment: @AndreaL. No, it isn't clearer. For matrices use the `amsmath` environments, which are already good for maintaining good distance between rows.

Comment: Yes, I do use the defined environments for the matrices but the problem is that my macro on `array` shrinkes the columns even when I don't need the eq.sys. and I'd like to know if there is a way to tell LaTeX to behave differently when it encounters a `\left\{`. I know that this issue isn't monumentally hard, but it's just something that I wanted to clearify from a long time :)

Comment: @AndreaL. You *don't* need to shrink `\arraycolsep`.

Comment: The only reason that keeps me from not doing so is the fact that the delimiter on the `array` envir. is too shifted to the left. This result is however obtained *only with the method in LyX* so I simply corrected it "the hard way". Regarding to only LaTeX I'll use always `dcases` from `mathtools`.