# Typeset a system of equations in LyX

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I want to create an system of equation in LyX, like this:

> [image: equation]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The answer can be found directly at [my previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132907/modify-locally-the-array-environment-for-equation-systems), there is a step-by-step procedure that will keep you from writing tedious ERT directly on LyX. Oh, by the way, let me know if I'll have to add an answer here (just for coherence).

Answer (score 8):

You can try the [`systeme`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\systeme{
x_1  -  x_3  =  0.2,
-\dfrac{1}{2} x_1  +  x_2  -  \dfrac{1}{4} x_3  =  -1.425,
x_1  -  \dfrac{1}{2} x_2  +  x_3  =  2
}

\end{document}
```

(I have found it...) Issuing the command

```
\syslineskipcoeff{2}
```

before the `\systeme` makes it look better (IMHO):

[image]

Comment: LyX is high-level processor, we should try to avoid explicit TeX whenever possible.

Comment: @juliohm LyX may be “high level”, but you *don't* obtain the same result with the way you suggest in your answer, do you?

Comment: @downvoter is your down vote because it is not the best way to go in LyX? I'm not a LyX expert, but please explain why you've downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

In math display mode, you can just type in the first equation, then press `Ctrl+Enter`, type in the second, and so on.

If alignment of columns is important, you do the same procedure but within an appropriate environment such as `Insert -> Math -> Aligned Environment`.

Comment: I think the OP wants a proper alignment inside every inlined equation that belongs to the system. In order to achieve this a column separation macro could be defined in the preamble, (i.e. modifying the `array` envir.); I'm saying this because the result for `Ctrl+Enter` *won't* re-create the system wanted.

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure that it is you that downvoted my answer. I agree that it is not the best way to go in LyX. But really do you think that your answer is better? BTW: I won't downvote your answer, anyway...

Comment: @karlkoeller, how is your answer specific to LyX? It's for sure a good answer.

Comment: @AndreaL., my answer is targeted to the specific little system of equations illustrated in the question, I should have designed a better solution though. It's just a trade-off between how much you bother with alignment or not. LyX also has direct insertion for `array`,`aligned`,`cases`,... that follows the same idea with `Ctrl+Enter`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @juliohm Please, can you show the result you're getting? Otherwise your answer can't help the OP. Anyway, I don't think you can *easily* get the same result with your suggestion as with `systeme`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want aligned equations with a left curly bracket:

[image]

or any "more aligned" variant:

[image]

then...

- Menu `Insert | Math | Delimiters`, then unselect `Keep matched` and select a curly bracket for the left delimiter, and `None` for the right delimiter. Click the `Insert` button:

  [image]
- Populate the box inserting an `AlignedAt` environment. Menu `Insert | Math | AMS AlignedAt Environment`. This gives you a row of two columns.
- Insert as many columns you need to match your custom alignment (button from array toolbar). Columns come in pairs "flush right -->|<-- flush left" alignment, but you can add an additional empty column to invert the alignment of columns on the right (proceed from left to right). Empty columns take no space on the rendered document.
- Enter your first equation. Add as many rows as you need using `Ctrl-Enter`. Be sure the cursor is at the end of the first row, and the status bar displays `align AlignedAt` and not `align`. Else you will add rows, but not inside the `AlignedAt` environment:

  [image]

---

For information, the code generated is:

```
[
\left\{
  \begin{alignedat}{4}
    x_{1} &  &  &  & -x_{3} & = &  & 0.2\\
    -\frac{1}{2}x_{1} &  & +x_{2} &  & -\frac{1}{4}x_{3} & = &  & -1.425\\
    x_{1} &  & -\frac{1}{2}x_{2} &  & +x_{3} & = &  & 2
  \end{alignedat}
\right.
\]
```